# Tableau Dashboard Default set to Yesterday by using Date Parameter

Tags: tableau-api

I have created daily dashboard which shows the data for single date selected from DATE PARAMETER (with ALL value). Which is OK for me that I can see the data for any date I want. 
But the problem is when I open my dashboard it is showing data for date which I selected in date parameter while publishing the Dashboard to Server/Online and Instead of that I want set it default to Yesterday. 
i.e. when I open my dashboard first time it should show yesterday's data and also there should option to change date as well to see another date data.
Can we achieve this using DATE PARAMETER (with ALL values)? If it is not possible then is there any other way?

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

Use a relative date filter instead of a parameter. Just be sure to save and publish the workbook with Yesterday as the relative date value.

Comment: Hi Sam, Thanks for the quick response. But can I also change date to see data for another selected day??
Ex: If I am running it Today then it will show the data for yesterday (i.e. 15th Oct 2018) but I also want to change filter value to lets say 1st Oct 2018 to see the data for that day . Can we do this using relative date filter?

Answer (score 0):

- 1, Create a calculation field d_yesterday, formula is TODAY()-1
  [image]
- 2, Create a parameter, data type is Date, value when workbook opens set to d_yesterday
  [image]
- 3, use the Date parameter in other calculations fields, or insert parameter into custom SQL query.